# Angular 2 - Using External Libraries

Tags: typescript, angular

I recently started using Angular2 (type script) and everything is going well until I tried to import an external javascript library https://github.com/marchock/vertical-blocks. I have tried a few methods but nothing works and I usually get an error displaying the library is not defined.

Comment: Please post how you try to import that library.

Comment: Here is an example for how to import jquery. The concept will be similar for most external libraries: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a global library so you do not need to `import` this. Instead use it as you would normally ex:

```
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent{
    verticalBlocks: any;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.verticalBlocks = new VerticalBlocks({
           ...    
        });
    }
}
```

and instead of `import` simply declare the variable `VerticalBlocks` so that TypeScript doesn't complain about you using it and knows that it's a global library using

```
declare var VerticalBlocks: any;
```

at the top of your `.ts` file.

Then simply add the script in your html as usual:

```
<script src="path/to/verticalblocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem.

Comment: If this fixed your problem be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer as it will help others in the future find the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: this helped me too - your comment though is interesting and sad from a software linguistic perspective - it's like telling someone to like something - its not really your fault but imagine if stackoverflow could parse "fixed" and automatically check it - it could also simply ask you before you comment too

Comment: @headwinds agreed. And I also have a moral dilema with the comment, which is why I usually do not post the above comment. I agree that a mechanism would be nice to educate new users to the concept of "accepting" answers. Your point is valid though about the "like this post", or "give me rep" interpretations of the comment.

Comment: @snareChops it would be interesting to know just how much +1 increases finding it - for me, it was on the first page of google within the top 3 with 0 likes and with -2 on the question. So maybe it doesn't really matter as long as people are clicking on the link. Beside new users, the strange and challenging thing is to continue to get long time users to also accept answers. I hope I'm not the only one reads something helpful and simply forgets to +1 it

Comment: doing this breaks tests for us. Looking for a way around this ATM. Reply if you have one :)

Comment: @MildFuzz There are many, many, many different ways to use 3rd party libraries, and the correct way for YOU depends on your use case. Would be happy to help if you post a new question with details on your use case.

Comment: using declare var is breaking in AoT mode @SnareChops any thoughts on this to make it work in AoT

Comment: Hey, I could do it in a more "angular2" way, by adding it in `.angular-cli.json`, in the `script` section, then no need to add it in index.html. See https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/